# Weird utf8 conversion problem in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

So I'm working on a project that is taking data from a file, in the file some lines require utf8 symbols but are encoded oddly, they are \xC6 for example rather than being \Æ

If I do as follows:

```
$name = "\xC6ther";
$name = preg_replace('/x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/', '&#$1;', $name);
echo utf8_encode($name);
```

It works fine. I get this:

```
Æther
```

But if I pull the same data from MySQL, and do as follows:

```
$name = $row['OracleName'];
$name = preg_replace('/x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/', '\&#$1;', $name);
$name = utf8_encode($name);
```

Then I receive this as output:

```
\&#C6;ther
```

Anyone know why this is?

As requested, vardump of $row['OracleName'];

```
string(15) "xC6ther Barrier"
```

Answer (score 1):

on your second preg_replace why there is a `\`

```
preg_replace('/x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/', '&#$1;', $name);
```

ok I think there is some confusion here. you regular expression is matching something like `x66` and would replace that by '&#66', which seems to be some `html entities` encoding to me but you are using `utf8_encode` which do that (from manual):

> utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8

so the things would never get converted ... (or to be more precise the '&#66' would remains '&#66' since they are all same characters in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8)

also to be noted on your first snippet you use `\xC6` but this would never get caught by the `preg_replace` since it's already encoded character. The `\x` means the next hex number (0x00 ~ 0xFF) would be drop in the string as is. it won't make a string `xC6`

So I am kind of confused of what you really wanna do. what the preg_replace is all about?

if you want to convert HTML entities to UTF-8 look into `mb_convert_encoding` ([manual](http://us.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)), if you want to do the reverse, code in HTML entities from some UTF-8 look into `htmlentities` ([manual](http://us.php.net/htmlentities))

and if it has nothing to do with all of that and you want to simply change encoding `mb_convert_encoding` is still there.

Comment: When the data is pulled from MySQL it lacks the leading \, though the data is in the mysql table itself.

Comment: sorry I missed your point, can you show us how look `$row['OracleName']` with `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, on the SQL pull I missed an 'x' in the preg_replace

```
preg_replace('/x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/', '&#x$1;', $name);
```

Once I added in the x, it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Trick: I really don't know what you doing **but** if your problem is fix that's nice

Comment: @Trick: right the number is in hex so should be `&#xNN`, but I am still concerned about your reg exp matching for example `xaa` as being some encoding where it's not